# Authenticating Asp.NET CORE web application from Xamarin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xamarin, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a ASP.NET Core web application, having builtin authentication.

How can I authenticate Xamarin native mobile app with web app and use web services?

Is there any Xamarin library for authenticating Microsoft Identity Server?

I found an article describing creating web service backend in ASP.NET core, but it omitted authentication (**why**?) :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mobile/native-mobile-backend

Answer (score 3):

In the article they use Web API template, problem is that ASP.NET Core does support personal authentication from a box (at least for right now)

Take a look at this project [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples). It's really easy to use and thay have a lot of examples how to build your own authentication service based on ASP.NET Core Web API. There is only one drawback of this project (by my opinion) - from the box OpenIddict supports only `EF Core` as data access library, but you can implement your own provider.

Comment: remark that EF is an object-relational mapper, not database provider. And you may simply configure it to use another DB, like PostgreSQL, instead if SQL.

Comment: May be it was not clear but by provider I mean not EF, I mean OpenIddict data provider, If you want work with OpenIddict and EF 6.x as example than you have to implement your own data provider for OpenIddict.

Answer (score 3):

There´s no Xamarin client for *Microsoft Identity Server* per se, but you can use oAuth2. It´s pretty standard.

Implementing an oAuth2 server like [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict), [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) or [AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server) you can use any oAuth2 client to authenticate, either way from a javascript application or Xamarin.

For Xamarin/.NET clients, there is an awesome client (PCL) called [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2).